# How to store data from txt file into 2d array java?

Tags: multidimensional-array

and store it into an int 2d array roomLayout = new int[numberOfRooms//=5][Arr.length];

This is what i got until now

```
str = gamemap.readLine();

String[] strArr = str.split(",");
System.out.println(str);
roomLayout = new int[numberOfRooms][str.length];
for (String number : strArr)
{
    int strToInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.print(number);
}
```

Comment: `roomLayout` assignment can be done like  `roomLayout[0][0] = 2;`

Comment: You need to explain why you expect such outcome - what is your logic.  Where does `numberOfRooms` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on with the following approach.

```
String yourString="2\n1,3,5\n2,5\n3,4,2\n5";    //Added newline characters for each newline

String lines[]=yourString.split("\n");
int roomLayout[][]=new int[lines.length][];

// for each line, split them and store them in your 2d array
for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    String parts[]=lines[i].split(",");
    int[] numbers=new int[parts.length];
    for(int j=0;j<parts.length;j++){
        numbers[j]=Integer.parseInt(parts[j]);
    }
    // assign your row as a row in the roomLayout.
    roomLayout[i]=numbers;
}

// Whenever you access the array, that is i'th room (indexed from 0)
// access allowed rooms as
for(int x=0;x<rooLayout[i].length;x++){
    System.out.println(roomLayout[i][x]);
}
```

Otherwise you can go with `ArrayLists`, which is a good alternative in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // all lines in file
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map.txt"));

    String line;

    // read lines in file
    while ((line = in.readLine())!=null){
        lines.add(line);
    }

    in.close();

    // create new 2d array
    int[][] map = new int[lines.size()][];

    // loop through array for each line
    for (int q = 0; q < map.length; q++){
        // get the rooms by separating by ","
        String[] rooms = lines.get(q).split(",");

        // size 2d array
        map[q] = new int[rooms.length];

        // loop through and add to array's second dimension
        for (int w = 0; w < rooms.length; w++){
            map[q][w] = Integer.parseInt(rooms[w]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map[q]));
    }
}
```

The output would be the following:

```
[2]
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 5]
[3, 4, 2]
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no objections about using Java 8, you can take this easier approach:

```
public static int[][] readRoomLayout(String fileName) throws IOException {

    int[][] roomLayout = null;

    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
    Function<String, int[]> toIntArrayFunction = string -> {
        String[] splitted = string.split(",");
        return Arrays.stream(splitted).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    };
    List<int[]> rooms = Files.lines(filePath).map(toIntArrayFunction)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    roomLayout = rooms.toArray(new int[rooms.size()][]);

    return roomLayout;
}
```